# How to remove duplicate property from a list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, console

Hello i have a console app with which I have to fetch data from few tables and create a excel file out of it, here is my code

```
 var Result = (from a in Db.tbl_ApplicantMaster
    join b in Db.tbl_App_Process on a.APP_ID equals b.APID
    join c in Db.tbl_Process on b.ProcessID equals c.ID
    join d in Db.tbl_Nationality on a.Nationality equals d.country_code
    join e in Db.tbl_AgencyMaster on a.Agn_ID equals e.AgID
    select new ExcelData
    {
        Name = a.Name,
        AppId = a.APP_ID,
        ProcessName = c.Process,
        StartDate = b.StartTime.ToString(),
        EndDate = b.EndTime.ToString(),
        Nationality = d.country_enName,
        Agency = e.AgencyName,
        }).ToList();
                
var File = new FileInfo(@"C:\path\ExcelSheet.xlsx");
              
await  GetExcelFile.ExportDataToExcel(Result, File);
```

And This is the Code I use to create an Excel file

```
 public static async Task ExportDataToExcel(List <ExcelData>  data,FileInfo File)
        {
           

            try
            {
               

                DeleteIfExists(File);
                ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
                using (var Package =new ExcelPackage(File))
                {

                    var Ws = Package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(Name: "MainReport");
                    var range = Ws.Cells[Address: "A1"].LoadFromCollection(data, true);
                    range.AutoFitColumns();

                    await Package.SaveAsync();

                }
               
               
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                
                throw;
            }
        }
```

This is my Model

```
 public class ExcelData{
        public int AppId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ProcessName { get; set; }
        public string StartDate { get; set; }
        public string EndDate { get; set; }
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
        public string Agency { get; set; }
        public double No_of_Days { get; set; }

    }
```

with this I am able to get the required data and even create a excel sheet from it but the excel sheet requires to be in a specific pattern where the applicant name should be shown only and then the date and name of each process, every applicant has 16 process so its not good to repeat the same name in each column with the process, the current data comes as following

```
ApplicantID:111
Name: X
ProcessName:Licence
startDate:10-10-2021
EndDate: 20-10-2021

ApplicantID:111
Name:x
ProcessName:TOIEC Test
start date:10-10-2021
End Date: 20-10-2021

ApplicantID:111
Name:x
ProcessName:Physical Test
start date:10-10-2021
End Date: 20-10-2021
```

but I want it to be like

```
ApplicantID:111
Name: X

ProcessName:Licence
startDate:10-10-2021
EndDate: 20-10-2021

ProcessName:TOIEC Test
start date:10-10-2021
End Date: 20-10-2021

ProcessName:Physical Test
start date:10-10-2021
End Date: 20-10-2021
```

How can I achieve this in C# ? do I have to use any thirdparty libs for this? Please Help Me Out,ThankYou

Comment: It depends how you create an excel file out of this. The solution will be different whether you are adding the lines to the excel sheet in a loop statement or whether you are calling an export function requiring a collection of prepared line data. Please, show us how you are exporting to excel.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thankyou for taking your time to go through my question, I have edited the post with more details. kindly check it again and reply if you have any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `ExcelData` class and make `AppId` and `Name` nullable (since `Name` is a string you have to this only if you are working with nullable reference types).

Then add an `orderby` to your query and order the items by `a.APP_ID`:

```cs
var Result = (from a in Db.tbl_ApplicantMaster
    join b in Db.tbl_App_Process on a.APP_ID equals b.APID
    join c in Db.tbl_Process on b.ProcessID equals c.ID
    join d in Db.tbl_Nationality on a.Nationality equals d.country_code
    join e in Db.tbl_AgencyMaster on a.Agn_ID equals e.AgID
    orderby a.APP_ID
    select new ExcelData {
        Name = a.Name,
        AppId = a.APP_ID,
        ProcessName = c.Process,
        StartDate = b.StartTime.ToString(),
        EndDate = b.EndTime.ToString(),
        Nationality = d.country_enName,
        Agency = e.AgencyName,
    }).ToList();
```

Now you can process the excel data list and set duplicate `AppId` and `Name` to null:

```cs
int? lastAppId = null;
foreach (var item in Result) {
    if (item.AppId == lastAppId) {
        item.AppId = null;
        item.Name = null;
    } else {
        lastAppId = item.AppId;
    }
}
```

This probably not perfect, but since we must pass elements of a single type to `LoadFromCollection`, we are somewhat limited. I don't know whether it works to insert `null` items into the list. If Excel inserts empty lines, this would help doing some grouping. something like this:

```cs
for (int i = Result.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var item = Result[i];
    if (item.AppId == lastAppId) {
        item.AppId = null;
        item.Name = null;
    } else {
        lastAppId = item.AppId;
        Result.Insert(i, null);
    }
}
```

Note that this loops the list in the reverse order, so that inserting the null entry does not change the index of the not yet processed items.

Comment: Thank you so much, with this I'm able to remove duplicate name and id, now I only have to figure out how to print related data in a single row.